# Is it possible to map a function over a Vec without allocating a new Vec?

Tags: rust

I have the following:

```
enum SomeType {
    VariantA(String),
    VariantB(String, i32),
}

fn transform(x: SomeType) -> SomeType {
    // very complicated transformation, reusing parts of x in order to produce result:
    match x {
        SomeType::VariantA(s) => SomeType::VariantB(s, 0),
        SomeType::VariantB(s, i) => SomeType::VariantB(s, 2 * i),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![
        SomeType::VariantA("hello".to_string()),
        SomeType::VariantA("bye".to_string()),
        SomeType::VariantB("asdf".to_string(), 34),
    ];
}
```

I would now like to call `transform` on each element of `data` and store the resulting value back in `data`. I could do something like `data.into_iter().map(transform).collect()`, but this will allocate a new `Vec`. Is there a way to do this in-place, reusing the allocated memory of `data`? There once was `Vec::map_in_place` in Rust but it has been removed some time ago.

As a work-around, I've added a `Dummy` variant to `SomeType` and then do the following:

```
for x in &mut data {
    let original = ::std::mem::replace(x, SomeType::Dummy);
    *x = transform(original);
}
```

This does not feel right, and I have to deal with `SomeType::Dummy` everywhere else in the code, although it should never be visible outside of this loop. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: See also [Using map with Vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30026893/155423).

Comment: You should change the signature of `transform()` to accept mutable references instead of consuming `SomeType`.

Comment: Yes it would be easy with a mutable reference, but `transform()` does some really complicated transformation, in particular re-using parts of the passed in `x` in order to produce the result and this is much easier to do in a "functional" style like this (if possible at all, using a mutable reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible in general because the size of each element might change as the mapping is performed (`fn transform(u8) -> u32`).

Even when the sizes are the same, it's non-trivial.

In *this case*, you don't need to create a `Dummy` variant because creating an empty `String` is cheap; only 3 pointer-sized values and no heap allocation:

```
impl SomeType {
    fn transform(&mut self) {
        use SomeType::*;

        let old = std::mem::replace(self, VariantA(String::new()));

        // Note this line for the detailed explanation

        *self = match old {
            VariantA(s) => VariantB(s, 0),
            VariantB(s, i) => VariantB(s, 2 * i),
        };
    }
}
```

```
for x in &mut data {
    x.transform();
}
```

An alternate implementation that just replaces the `String`:

```
impl SomeType {
    fn transform(&mut self) {
        use SomeType::*;

        *self = match self {
            VariantA(s) => {
                let s = std::mem::replace(s, String::new());
                VariantB(s, 0)
            }
            VariantB(s, i) => {
                let s = std::mem::replace(s, String::new());
                VariantB(s, 2 * *i)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In general, yes, you have to create **some** dummy value to do this generically and with safe code. Many times, you can wrap your whole element in `Option` and call `Option::take` to achieve the same effect .

See also:

- [Change enum variant while moving the field to the new variant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557412/155423)

## Why is it so complicated?

See this [proposed and now-closed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1736) for lots of related discussion. My understanding of that RFC (and the complexities behind it) is that there's an time period where your value would have an undefined value, which is **not safe**. If a panic were to happen at that exact second, then when your value is dropped, you might trigger undefined behavior, a bad thing.

If your code were to panic at the commented line, then the value of `self` is a concrete, known value. If it were some unknown value, dropping that string would try to drop that unknown value, and we are back in C. This is the purpose of the `Dummy` value - to always have a known-good value stored.

You even hinted at this (emphasis mine):

> I have to deal with `SomeType::Dummy` everywhere else in the code, although it **should** never be visible outside of this loop

That "should" is the problem. During a panic, that dummy value *is* visible.

See also:

- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423)
- [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423)
- [How do I move out of a struct field that is an Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031002/155423)

The [now-removed implementation of `Vec::map_in_place`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.3.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L787-L961) spans almost 175 lines of code, most of having to deal with unsafe code and reasoning why it is actually safe! Some crates have re-implemented this concept and attempted to make it safe; you can see an example in [Sebastian Redl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448220/155423).

Answer (score 10):

Your first problem is not `map`, it's `transform`.

`transform` takes ownership of its argument, while `Vec` has ownership of its arguments. Either one has to give, and poking a hole in the `Vec` would be a bad idea: what if `transform` panics?

---

The best fix, thus, is to change the signature of `transform` to:

```
fn transform(x: &mut SomeType) { ... }
```

then you can just do:

```
for x in &mut data { transform(x) }
```

---

Other solutions will be clunky, as they will need to deal with the fact that `transform` might panic.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `map_in_place` in terms of the [`take_mut`](https://github.com/Sgeo/take_mut) or [`replace_with`](https://github.com/alecmocatta/replace_with) crates:

```
fn map_in_place<T, F>(v: &mut [T], f: F)
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T,
{
    for e in v {
        take_mut::take(e, f);
    }
}
```

However, if this panics in the supplied function, the program aborts completely; you cannot recover from the panic.

Alternatively, you could supply a placeholder element that sits in the empty spot while the inner function executes:

```
use std::mem;

fn map_in_place_with_placeholder<T, F>(v: &mut [T], f: F, mut placeholder: T)
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T,
{
    for e in v {
        let mut tmp = mem::replace(e, placeholder);
        tmp = f(tmp);
        placeholder = mem::replace(e, tmp);
    }
}
```

If this panics, the placeholder you supplied will sit in the panicked slot.

Finally, you could produce the placeholder on-demand; basically replace `take_mut::take` with `take_mut::take_or_recover` in the first version.