# How do I convert a Vec<T> to a Vec<U> without copying the vector?

Tags: rust

I want to convert a `Vec<T>` to a `Vec<U>` where `T` is a primitive of some sort and `U` is a newtype of `T`: `struct U(T)`.

I tried something like this:

```
struct Foo(u32);

fn do_something_using_foo(buffer: &mut Vec<Foo>) {}

fn main() {
    let buffer: Vec<u32> = vec![0; 100];

    do_something_using_foo(&mut buffer as Vec<Foo>);
}
```

I don't want to make a copy of the vector, I want to wrap the `u32` fields in the newtype `Foo`.

This gives the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> main.rs:8:28
  |
8 |     do_something_using_foo(&mut buffer as Vec<Foo>);
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected mutable reference, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
  |
  = note: expected type `&mut std::vec::Vec<Foo>`
         found type `std::vec::Vec<Foo>`
  = help: try with `&mut &mut buffer as Vec<Foo>`

error: non-scalar cast: `&mut std::vec::Vec<u32>` as `std::vec::Vec<Foo>`
 --> main.rs:8:28
  |
8 |     do_something_using_foo(&mut buffer as Vec<Foo>);
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error(s)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you need to access the `Vec<T>` as a `&[U]`, `&mut [U]`, or a `&mut Vec<U>`?  (Hint: The slice alternatives are vastly simpler).

Comment: @bluss for my situation `&mut [U]` would be acceptable although `&mut Vec<U>` is preferable.

Comment: If `&mut [U]` is acceptable, then [it's preferred over `&mut Vec<U>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).

Comment: There was a time long long ago where `Vec` had a `fn map_in_place<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Vec<U>` method, that would work when `T` and `U` were the same size. It was removed in Rust 1.4, but there seem to be a crate that does that. Probably overkill though in that case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You *cannot* change the type of a value in place in safe Rust. There is no guarantee that the two types will have the same size, alignment, or semantics.

This applies to a single value (`T` -> `U`) as well as aggregate values (`Vec<T>` -> `Vec<U>`, `HashMap<K1, V1>` -> `HashMap<K2, V2>`). Note that aggregate values are really just a special case of "single" values.

## Create a new vector

The most straight-forward solution:

```rust
let buffer2 = buffer.into_iter().map(Foo).collect();
```

In cases where the compiler can tell that you aren't actually changing important things, this becomes effectively a no-op:

```rust
fn convert(b: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<Foo> {
    b.into_iter().map(Foo).collect()
}
```

x86_64 assembly output for Rust 1.54 with optimizations:

```
playground::convert:
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movq    (%rsi), %rcx
    movups  8(%rsi), %xmm0
    movq    %rcx, (%rdi)
    movups  %xmm0, 8(%rdi)
    retq
```

Unfortunately, this lightweight transformation isn't currently a guaranteed property, only an implementation detail.

## Use generics

You could adjust `do_something_using_foo` to take in a generic type and have both `Foo` and `u32` implement a trait:

```rust
use std::borrow::{Borrow, BorrowMut};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Foo(u32);

impl Borrow<u32> for Foo {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &u32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl BorrowMut<u32> for Foo {
    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> &mut u32 {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

fn do_something_using_foo<T>(buffer: &mut [T])
where
    T: BorrowMut<u32>,
{
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer_u32 = vec![0u32; 100];
    let mut buffer_foo = vec![Foo(0); 100];

    do_something_using_foo(&mut buffer_u32);
    do_something_using_foo(&mut buffer_foo);
}
```

## Unsafe Rust

It's technically possible — you can shoot yourself in the foot as much as you'd like.

You can use something like [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) **if** you know what you are doing.

However, it's undefined behavior to use `transmute` with `Vec` as the representation of `Vec` is not defined. Instead, see [Sven Marnach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081958/155423).

See also:

- [Using map with Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30026893/155423)
- [Converting a Vec<u32> to Vec<u8> in-place and with minimal overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49690459/155423)

Comment: *There is no guarantee that the two types will have the same size*. At least, this can be verified: `std::mem::size_of`.

Comment: For a no-op in-place conversion, you don't need anything nearly as complex as the old `map_in_place()`. The reason for its complexity was mainly that it had to deal with the intermediate states when parts of the vector already have type `U` and the remainder still is type `T`. Getting this right even in the event of panics is quite involved. If the source and destination types have the same memory layout though, and you only want to _reinterpret_ the memory as a different type, then this can be done relatively easily.

Comment: The docs say that `transmute` is "equivalent to C’s memcpy under the hood", so I don't think this satisfies the criteria of "without copying the vector". I mention this because it's a high ranking Google result for "rust transmute without copying".

Comment: @detly yes, the **24 bytes** (on 64-bit machine) of the `Vec<T>` are copied. The data is not copied. Otherwise you'd need something like converting the 8 bytes of  `&Vec<T>`, which would still involve copying those 8 bytes.

Comment: I misread the docs then; I thought it would copy the entire underlying slice of `T` as well. Does this mean that transmuting a slice only copies the data that makes up the fat pointer, and not the contiguous array of data it points to?

Answer (score 17):

According to the [documentation of `std::mem::transmute()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html), using `Vec::from_raw_parts` combined with `ManuallyDrop` is the best option, as of Rust 1.38:

```
let v_from_raw = unsafe {
    // Ensure the original vector is not dropped.
    let mut v_clone = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(v_orig);
    Vec::from_raw_parts(v_clone.as_mut_ptr() as *mut U,
                        v_clone.len(),
                        v_clone.capacity())
};
```

The prerequisite for this is that `T` and `U` have the same size, the same minimum alignment and that all bit patterns that are valid for `T` are also valid for `U`. If you define `T` and `U` as in your question, you don't have a guarantee for this.

`struct U(T)` defines a tuple struct, and the memory layout of such a struct is completely undefined. However, it is possible to force the memory representations to be identical by using [the `transparent` representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-transparent-representation):

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct U(T);
```

## Future options

Nightly Rust has [`Vec::into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_raw_parts), which reduces the amount of code and places to go wrong:

```
#![feature(vec_into_raw_parts)]

fn convert_using_into_raw_parts(v: Vec<T>) -> Vec<U> {
    let (ptr, len, cap) = v.into_raw_parts();
    unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr as *mut U, len, cap) }
}
```