# Is there a zero-cost way of converting a slice of structs into a slice of newtypes over that struct?

Tags: rust

If I have a slice of structs `&[Foo]`, and I've defined a newtype for `Foo` called `NewFoo`, is there a zero-cost way to convert `&[Foo]` to `&[NewFoo]`?

The best I've come up with is, which isn't zero-cost:

```
let _ = foos.iter().map(|foo| NewFoo(*foo)).collect::<Vec<NewFoo>>();
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308759/how-do-i-convert-a-vect-to-a-vecu-without-copying-the-vector/48309116#48309116) might be of interest.

Comment: Rust does not guarantee that a newtype has the same memory layout as the original type. If you are using a `struct` for the newtype, you can use `#[repr(transparent)]` to get this guarantee.

Comment: I've added an answer to the question Michail linked above, and I voted to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Relevant: [`slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html)