# Is there any way to safely cast from Vec<T> to Vec<NewtypeOfT> without copying the content of the vector?

Tags: rust

For a `struct Asdf(i32);` using the [default](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-default-representation) representation the memory size and alignment seem to be the same as for a raw `i32` primitive.

Is there a way to cast from `Vec<Asdf>` to `Vec<i32>` that doesn't require any assumptions on memory equality of `Asdf` and `i32`? An ideal solution would be where the compiler and optimizer detect that a conversion can be made as a zero-cost cast at compile time and fall back to a copy or throw a compiler error when this is no longer the case (for example if someone were to add a second parameter to `Asdf`).

#### Approaches tried:

**Safe, copy based solution**

When mapping over `IntoIter`, the optimizer at `opt-level = 3` does not get rid of the copy.

```
fn convert(from: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Asdf> {
    from.into_iter().map(|p| Asdf(p)).collect()
}
```

**Unsafe solutions**

I know that it is possible to achieve a copy-free conversion by using `Vec::from_raw_parts` or `std::mem::transmute`. Is there any way to do this without `unsafe` code?

```rust
fn convert_unsafe(v_orig: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Asdf> {
    let mut v_orig = v_orig;
    let v_from_raw = unsafe {
        Vec::from_raw_parts(
            v_orig.as_mut_ptr() as *mut Asdf,
            v_orig.len(),
            v_orig.capacity(),
        )
    };
    std::mem::forget(v_orig);
    v_from_raw
}

fn convert_transmute(v_orig: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Asdf> {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<Vec<i32>, Vec<Asdf>>(v_orig) }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a Vec<T> to a Vec<U> without copying the vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308759/how-do-i-convert-a-vect-to-a-vecu-without-copying-the-vector) (See especially Sven Marnach's answer, which addresses your case specifically.)

Comment: *I know that it is possible to achieve a copy-free conversion by using [...] `std::mem::transmute`* —  This is [not true](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html#alternatives); it is undefined behavior to transmute a `Vec` as it is `repr(Rust)`:

Comment: @trentcl: Yes, that question sufficiently matches mine. The remarks on `repr(transparent)` were especially valuable to me.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I was aware of the fact, that doing so is "Undefined Behavior, and a bad idea". Both `convert_unsafe` and `convert_transmute` were based on the `Turning a Vec<&T> into a Vec<Option<&T>>` example from the page that you had linked. I'm sorry for not expressing myself more clearly. I was trying to give an example of what I want to avoid – not imply that such a bad practice would be sound. Thank you for your update on Sven Marnach's anwer.

Comment: @TimBodeit Great! I'd like to raise a minor clarification wrt Shepmaster's comment: `convert_transmute` is *always* UB, but `convert_unsafe` may be sound when `Asdf` is `repr(transparent)`. They are both solutions that use `unsafe`, but they are not both "equally unsafe" because one is *always* wrong whereas the other is only *sometimes* wrong.